# Order pieces in an authoryear-style citation call-out chronologically

Tags: citing, natbib

I'm making a document with citations using the `natbib` citation management package and the `humannat` bibliography style.

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{humannat}
```

If I cite multiple articles using `\citep`, I would like them to be in chronological order automatically. E.g., instead of

```
(Naldini, 2015; Shih and Lindley, 2006)
```

I would like

```
(Shih and Lindley, 2006; Naldini, 2015)
```

Additionally, I would like to have the bibliography sorted alphabetically by authors' surnames.

Is there a simple way to achieve this objective?

Comment: I'm not aware of the `bibtex` program, the `natbib` package, or the `humannat` bibliography style providing support for your formatting objective. Just out of curiosity: Is there something stopping you from listing the arguments of `\citep` in chronological order?

Comment: Also, please advise as to what should happen if two or more of the arguments of `\citep` happen to have the same publication year. Should those arguments be sorted alphabetically by authors' surnames?

Comment: In fact, no. But it might help me if i don't need to pay attention to it. I'm new to LaTex, and i used Mendeley before in Word. Mendeley was able to do this, so i was wondering if there is a LaTeX equivalent. If two or more arguments of have the same publication year, it should indeed be sorted alphabetically by author. Thanks for your reply!